# What is the answer that best completes the pattern?

Tags: pattern, visual

What is the answer that best completes the pattern?

[image: puzzle]

Answer (score 16):

The answer is

> C

because

> in each row, the third panel contains only the things present in both of the previous two panels.

Comment: Bravo! I had to look at your solution since I couldn't get it right. Where can I find more of these (preferably with answers)?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is

> "C".
> Because in each row, the third pattern is the intersection
> (or the common part) of first & second pattern.

Comment: This answer as already given 5 hours before yours, and used spoilers to avoid spoiling the fun of others. I do not see much benefit in double posting, but at the very least make use of spoilers too to avoid ruining others' fun.